# Ubuntu Mate shows no panels, but with a new user shows. How I can reset the settings?

Tags: 18.04, mate, ubuntu-mate

I made a fresh install of Ubuntu MATE to VirtualboxVm but for some reason I have no panels:

[image: Ubuntu Mate]

But I did a new user and the panels show as new as possible. I created a new user and shows the panels as good as new:

[image: Mate as a new user]

In the first picture I am logged in as `user` and on the second one I am loged in as `user2` how I can reset the Mate settings in `user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just delete the folder `~/.config` in a command line inteface, but not in a GUI terminal. Just follow these steps:

1. Press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F2`
2. Login
3. Kill all user's sessions with `sudo skill -KILL -u ^username^`
4. Relogin
5. Type `rm -rf ~/.config`
6. Press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F7`
7. Login into GUI.

You hace sucessfully reset the MATE desktop. In case f a problem just copy the `~/.config` from another user (sudo access required).